U-Boot Compilation Fails with region `.sram' overflowed
I am using Yocto Kirkstone to build an image for a Compulab i.MX8 device.
The overarching meta layer is this one: https://github.com/compulab-yokneam/meta-bsp-imx8mp
Everything builds with Yocto except for U-Boot 2022.04: https://github.com/compulab-yokneam/u-boot-compulab
The build fails with this error:
| aarch64-poky-linux-ld.bfd: u-boot-spl section `.u_boot_list' will not fit in region `.sram'
| aarch64-poky-linux-ld.bfd: region `.sram' overflowed by 2744 bytes

If I follow Compulab's directions to setup a Linaro cross compiler and build U-Boot without Yocto, it compiles fine (https://github.com/compulab-yokneam/meta-bsp-imx8mp/blob/kirkstone/Documentation/toolchain.md#linaro-toolchain-how-to).
I have tried several suggestions found on google without success:

https://github.com/compulab-yokneam/meta-bsp-imx8mp/issues/25
https://github.com/varigit/uboot-imx/issues/3
https://u-boot.denx.narkive.com/ZR4QJLv3/sram-overflowed

I created a bbappend file and attempted to remove several SPL related options in the final u-boot .config that I do not need. However, it keeps failing with various "will not fit in region `.sram'" messages.
Sample compilation line with compiler flags:
|   aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  --sysroot=/home/developer/compulab-nxp-bsp/build-iot-gate-imx8plus/tmp/work/iot_gate_imx8plus-poky-linux/u-boot-compulab/2022.04-r0/recipe-sysroot -Wp,-MD,spl/drivers/clk/.clk-composite.o.d -nostdinc -isystem /home/developer/compulab-nxp-bsp/build-iot-gate-imx8plus/tmp/work/iot_gate_imx8plus-poky-linux/u-boot-compulab/2022.04-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/../../lib/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/11.3.0/include -Ispl/include -Iinclude  -I/home/developer/compulab-nxp-bsp/build-iot-gate-imx8plus/tmp/work/iot_gate_imx8plus-poky-linux/u-boot-compulab/2022.04-r0/git/include  -I/home/developer/compulab-nxp-bsp/build-iot-gate-imx8plus/tmp/work/iot_gate_imx8plus-poky-linux/u-boot-compulab/2022.04-r0/git/arch/arm/include -include /home/developer/compulab-nxp-bsp/build-iot-gate-imx8plus/tmp/work/iot_gate_imx8plus-poky-linux/u-boot-compulab/2022.04-r0/git/include/linux/kconfig.h  -I/home/developer/compulab-nxp-bsp/build-iot-gate-imx8plus/tmp/work/iot_gate_imx8plus-poky-linux/u-boot-compulab/2022.04-r0/git/drivers/clk -Ispl/drivers/clk -D__KERNEL__ -D__UBOOT__ -DCONFIG_SPL_BUILD -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-format-security -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -std=gnu11 -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-PIE -Os -fno-stack-protector -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-zero-length-bounds -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fmacro-prefix-map=/home/developer/compulab-nxp-bsp/build-iot-gate-imx8plus/tmp/work/iot_gate_imx8plus-poky-linux/u-boot-compulab/2022.04-r0/git/= -g -fstack-usage -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Werror=date-time -Wno-packed-not-aligned -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-stack-protector -D__ARM__ -mstrict-align -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -ffixed-r9 -mgeneral-regs-only -fno-common -ffixed-x18 -pipe -march=armv8-a+crc -D__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__=8 -mgeneral-regs-only    -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"clk_composite"'  -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"clk_composite"' -c -o spl/drivers/clk/clk-composite.o /home/developer/compulab-nxp-bsp/build-iot-gate-imx8plus/tmp/work/iot_gate_imx8plus-poky-linux/u-boot-compulab/2022.04-r0/git/drivers/clk/clk-composite.c

How can I fix this .sram overflowing issue?
